# Microsoft Bing Maps v7 Search Manager GeoCode errorCallBack

Tags: geocode, bing-maps

The issue happens during page refresh then browser is minimized or its tab with a map is inactive. Then Search Manager geocode function falls into errorCallback. Everything is working fine, if the page with the map is active (visible).

I checked e.request object in the errorCallback function and it contains correct "where" parameter, but no latitude and longitude nor any information about the error.

The issue can be reproduced in both Chrome and IE browsers.

HTML:
`<div id="map" class="map" style="height:270px; width:100%"></div>`

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&s=1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // global variables
    var apiKey = 'API_KEY_HIDDEN',
        map,
        searchManager;

    // sample data
    var siteData = [
        {"Name":"Starbucks","Address":"8400 SW Nimbus Ave 120","City":"Beaverton","State":"OR","Zip":"97008","Latitude":0,"Longitude":0},
        {"Name":"Subway","Address":"12160 SW Scholls Ferry Rd","City":"Tigard","State":"OR","Zip":"97223","Latitude":0,"Longitude":0}
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetMap();
        setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 60000);
    });

    function GetMap() {    

        // initialize the map
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            credentials: apiKey,
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
            zoom: 1
        });

        // load search module
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', {
            callback: function () {
                searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                $.each(siteData, function(index, clientSite) {
                    GeoCodeQuery(clientSite);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function GeoCodeQuery(clientSite) {

        // set search parameters
        var searchRequest = {
            where: clientSite.Address + ', ' + clientSite.City + ', ' + clientSite.State + ' ' + clientSite.Zip,
            callback: function (data) {
                if (data && data.results && data.results.length > 0) {
                    clientSite.Latitude = data.results[0].location.latitude;
                    clientSite.Longitude = data.results[0].location.longitude;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('No results.');
                }
            },
            errorCallback: function (e) {
                console.log('Search error.');
            }
        };

        // make the geocode request
        searchManager.geocode(searchRequest);           
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues;

- You are missing a comma after your where parameter. This would make the searchRequest an invalid JSON object. Fixing this results in the first address being correctly geocoded. The second is throwing an error and this can be for a large number of reasons, the most likely is the next point.
- The Bing Maps V7 control was retired in June and will be shut down soon. Some of its backend services are already being taken down and thus it will have issues. You should be using Bing Maps V8 which replaced V7 over a year ago. You can find a migration guide here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx

Comment: Actually, the comma is in my original code.  I just missed it here, while was trying to compact and format code for StackOverflow.  Like, I mentioned in my comment - everything works if page (tab) with the map is visible. It only fails when a browser is minimized or tab with the map is inactive.  I did actually, tried this in v8, after making this post, by creating a simple map and using sample data - results were the same.  I ended up writing custom (and unfortunately slower) geocoding service to use it as a fallback for errors in Search Manager.

Comment: I am also wondering why would Search Manager needs a map in its constructor, if geocode query and results are independent of it (the map).  I also tried to populate "bounds" property to the geocode search request, thinking that they can not be calculated properly, but again - no luck.

Comment: The search manager uses the map view to help influence/weight the results. It also grabs a session key from the map. If you don't care about this you can simply use the REST location API directly: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#RestServices_JSONP